# Java Generics: Stream.map() returns "capture of ?" instead of "?"

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

I'm trying to build a `List` of Classes that implement a certain interface called `Interface`:

```
List<Class<? extends Interface>> myList= myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(myValue))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)   // Stream<Interface>
    .map(Interface::getClass) // Stream<Class<capture of ? extends Interface>>
    .distinct()
    .toList();
```

I added as comment the type of the elements in the Stream after `map()` is called.

The code iterates over all the entries in the map, and if their value is equal to `myValue`, then:

- first, gets the *instance* of type `Interface` (which is the *key* of the *entry*)
- then, gets the `Class` implementing the `Interface`.

`myMap` is defined as:

```
Map<Interface, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>()
```

The error I'm getting :

```
Incompatible types.
Found: 'java.util.List<java.lang.Class<capture<? extends application.interfaces.Interface>>>',
required: 'java.util.List<java.lang.Class<? extends application.interfaces.Interface>>'
```

I am clearly missing something about how *Generics* work in Java, but I am at a loss here. I suppose it's something related to the fact that the compiler cannot correctly reify my `?` wildcard.

Comment: Probably, you meant `entry.getValue().equals(myValue)`, **not** `entry.getValue() == myValue`

Comment: Yes, thanks for noticing, I'll update post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As *@Slaw* has pointed out in the comments, in this case `getClass()` is capable to provide the information about the generic type to the compiler.

According to the [*documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()):

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called.

Hence, at compile time, we would have a type `? extends Interface` and the reason of the observed behavior is related solely to peculiarities of **type inference** in Java.

In this case, when we are chaining methods after `map()` operation, the compiler fails to infer the type of the method reference `Interface::getClass` correctly based on the resulting type returned by the stream.

If we substitute `toList`, which expects elements of type `T` and produces `List<T>`, with `collect(Collectors.toList())`, in which collector is of type `Collector<? super T, A, R>`, the compiler would be able to do its job (here's a [*proof*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tN1)):

```
List<Class<? extends Interface>> myList = myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), myValue))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)   // Stream<Interface>
    .map(Interface::getClass) // Stream<Class<? extends Interface>>
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But to make type inference working with `toList()` we need to provide the generic type **explicitly**.

For instance, this code would compile, because the type of `Interface::getClass` could be inferred from the assignment context (here there are no operations after `map()`, hence `myStream` directly says what should be the return type of `map()`):

```
Stream<Class<? extends Interface>> myStream = myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), myValue))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .map(Interface::getClass);

List<Class<? extends Interface>> myList = myStream.distinct().toList();
```

A more handy way would be to use a so-called *Type Witness*:

```
Map<Interface, Integer> myMap = Map.of(new ClasA(), 1, new ClasB(), 1);
        
int myValue = 1;
        
List<Class<? extends Interface>> myList = myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), myValue))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)                               // Stream<Interface>
    .<Class<? extends Interface>>map(Interface::getClass) // Stream<Class<? extends Interface>>
    .distinct()
    .toList();
        
myList.forEach(c -> System.out.println(c.getSimpleName()));
```

*Output:*

```
ClasA
ClasB
```

*Dummy classes:*

```
interface Interface {}
class ClasA implements Interface {}
class ClasB implements Interface {}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know Type Witnesses even existed. I noted that you modified the predicate in the filter(). Is it for any particular reason?

Comment: Note: "_The actual result type is Class<? extends |X|> where |X| is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called_" – [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass())

Comment: @Slaw Right, and in Java generics get erased to `Object` type. So *erasure type*  `X`in the quote is nothing else but `Object`. And `? extends Object` ( `? extends X` ) effectively is the same as unknown type `?`.

Comment: @ralos I've modified it when I was reading your initial version (which used identity comparison `==`). You can use either `equals()`, or `Objects.equals()`. The latter has a small advantage, it's not hostile to `null`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Type erasure is not involved here, as we're talking about compile-time, when generics still exist. One would expect `Interface::getClass` to return a `Class<? extends Interface>`. From there, it would make sense to think you'd get a `Stream<Class<? extends Interface>>` from the `map(Interface::getClass)` call. That's apparently not the case but it's an understandable expectation.